# Deleted oAuth client ID by mistake, how to re-enable IAP

Tags: google-iap

I was playing around with IAP and somehow deleted its oAuth Client ID (IAP-App-Engine-app) which it created during IAP setup for App Engine.

Now, I am not able to use IAP. It is giving following error while enabling IAP on App Engine:

> Failed to change IAP state on App Engine app.

Is there a way I can use IAP again on my App Engine by somehow recreating its oAuth Client ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry you're running into this. It's a known bug, you can read a bit more [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123012920).  Cloud Console will leave the client ID alone if you already have one configured in your App Engine app's IAP settings.  The problem is that the Console isn't checking that the client ID still exists.  You can see the workaround at that link: use the App Engine admin API to reset the IAP settings, and then you can turn IAP on in the Console and it will create a new client ID for you.
  --Matthew, Google Cloud IAP engineering